# Problem to display QLabels in GridLayout in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

My Intention is to display five types of labels in two frames (left and right Frame).
In my case, the right frame, which contains two labels, is displayed or added as per my idea.

But in the Left frame, I face a problem. Added widgets display is not proper. The left frame is a GridLayout, In which we add three widgets. As of my idea, top widget is none or single line. Middle widget is a character and the bottim widget is either single, double or triple line.

[image]

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget,QFrame,QLabel,QHBoxLayout,QVBoxLayout,QGridLayout,QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont 

class Left_Right_FrameDesign(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,color_left_lrcd,color_right_lrcd,
                      frame_left_lrcd_width,frame_right_lrcd_width,
                      frame_lrcd_height):
        super().__init__()
        self.color_left_lrcd  = color_left_lrcd
        self.color_right_lrcd = color_right_lrcd
        self.frame_left_lrcd_width = frame_left_lrcd_width
        self.frame_right_lrcd_width = frame_right_lrcd_width
        self.frame_lrcd_height = frame_lrcd_height

        self.frame_left_lrcd = QFrame()
        self.frame_left_lrcd.setProperty("type","1")
        self.frame_left_lrcd.setFixedSize(self.frame_left_lrcd_width,self.frame_lrcd_height)

        self.frame_right_lrcd = QFrame()
        self.frame_right_lrcd.setProperty("type","1")
        self.frame_right_lrcd.setFixedHeight(self.frame_lrcd_height)
        self.frame_right_lrcd.setFixedWidth(self.frame_right_lrcd_width)

        self.principal_lrcd_layout  = QHBoxLayout()
        self.frame_left_lrcd_layout = QGridLayout(self.frame_left_lrcd)
        self.frame_right_lrcd_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.frame_right_lrcd)

        self.frame_left_lrcd_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.frame_right_lrcd_layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.frame_right_lrcd_layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.frame_left_lrcd_layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter| Qt.AlignVCenter)

        self.principal_lrcd_layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.principal_lrcd_layout.addWidget(self.frame_left_lrcd)
        self.principal_lrcd_layout.addWidget(self.frame_right_lrcd)
        self.principal_lrcd_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

class example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("My Widget Example")
        self.setStyleSheet(style_sheet())

        my_font_1 = QFont("Arial", 10, QFont.Bold)
        my_font_1.setLetterSpacing(QFont.AbsoluteSpacing, -6)
        my_font_en = QFont("Arial", 8, QFont.Bold)
        my_font_hi = QFont("Mangal", 11, )
        my_font_ta = QFont("Latha", 8,QFont.Bold)

        lbl_sline = ('\u2015' * 1)  # print single line
        lbl_dline = '\u003D' * 4  # print double line
        lbl_tline = ('\u2261' * 4)  # print tripleline

        text = {"lbl01": {"lan_1":"en_Accounts","lan_2":"ta_கணக்கியல்"    ,"char":"ta_ழ்","top_line":"0","bot_line":"1"},
                "lbl02": {"lan_1":"en_Manufacturing","lan_2":"hi_हिसाब किताब","char":"en_F8","top_line":"1","bot_line":"2"},
                "lbl03": {"lan_1":"en_Inventory","lan_2":"ta_சரக்கியல்"     ,"char":"hi_हि","top_line":"1","bot_line":"3"}}

        lst_mainkeys = list(text.keys())
        lst_subkeys  = list(text[lst_mainkeys[0]].keys())

        self.frame_design,self.lbl_lan1,self.lbl_lan2,self.lbl_tline,self.lbl_char,self.lbl_bline = {},{},{},{},{},{}
        self.lay = QHBoxLayout()
        self.lay.setSpacing(3)
        self.lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        for i, j in enumerate(lst_mainkeys):
            self.frame_design[i] = Left_Right_FrameDesign(color_left_lrcd="green", color_right_lrcd="blue",
                                                   frame_left_lrcd_width=50, frame_right_lrcd_width=200,
                                                   frame_lrcd_height= 40)
            for m,n in enumerate(lst_subkeys):
                name = j+"_"+str(m)
                self.lbl_lan1[name] = QLabel()
                self.lbl_lan2[name] = QLabel()
                self.lbl_tline[name] = QLabel()
                self.lbl_char[name] = QLabel()
                self.lbl_bline[name] = QLabel()
                self.temp_name =(text[j][n])

                if self.temp_name[:2] == "en":
                    self.myfont = my_font_en
                elif self.temp_name[:2] == "ta":
                    self.myfont = my_font_ta
                elif self.temp_name[:2] == "hi":
                    self.myfont = my_font_hi

                if n == "lan_1":
                    self.lbl_lan1[name].setText(text[j][n][3:])
                    self.lbl_lan1[name].setFont(self.myfont)
                    self.frame_design[i].frame_right_lrcd_layout.addWidget(self.lbl_lan1[name])
                elif  n == "lan_2":
                    self.lbl_lan2[name].setText(text[j][n][3:])
                    self.lbl_lan2[name].setFont(self.myfont)
                    self.frame_design[i].frame_right_lrcd_layout.addWidget(self.lbl_lan2[name])
                elif  n == "char":
                    self.lbl_char[name].setText(text[j][n][3:])
                    self.lbl_char[name].setFont(self.myfont)
                    self.frame_design[i].frame_left_lrcd_layout.addWidget(self.lbl_char[name],1,0)
                if n == "top_line":
                    if self.temp_name == 0:
                        pass
                    elif self.temp_name == 1:
                        self.lbl_tline[name].setText(lbl_sline)
                    self.frame_design[i].frame_left_lrcd_layout.addWidget(self.lbl_tline[name],0,0)
                if n == "bot_line":
                    if self.temp_name == 1:
                        self.lbl_bline[name].setText(lbl_sline)
                    elif self.temp_name == 2:
                        self.lbl_bline[name].setText(lbl_dline)
                    elif self.temp_name == 3:
                        self.lbl_bline[name].setText(lbl_tline)
                        self.lbl_bline[name].setText(text[j][n])
                    self.frame_design[i].frame_left_lrcd_layout.addWidget(self.lbl_bline[name],2,0)

            self.lay.addLayout(self.frame_design[i].principal_lrcd_layout)
        self.setLayout(self.lay)

def style_sheet():
    return """
    QFrame[type="1"] {background-color : rgb(188,212,114);}
    QFrame[type="1"]::hover{background-color:rgb(255, 223, 0);color: Black;}}"""

if __name__ =="__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = example()
    mainwindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Please try to rephrase the second part of your question as right now it's very confusing and it's unclear what would be the correct result or why.

Comment: Left part or left frame, added three widgets. But its display is not proper. As of my idea, top widget is none or single line. Middle widgetbis a character and the bottim widget is either single, double or triple line.@musicamante

Comment: Sorry, but that's still completely unclear. Try to simplify your example, clarify your explanation and eventually provide an image of the expected result.